# Searching an array using Parse iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to search a tableview that uses Parse to talk to a database. Anyway I think I am having a problem with my filter function. I have added some NSLogs but they are printing 0 when i should definitely have some values. I have looked at many different tutorials/forums but for some reason nothing is working. I always get no results. I believe the problem is in the filterResults method. The output i get is below.

```
2014-07-08 14:11:15.488 Truthly[3674:184774] (
)
2014-07-08 14:11:15.488 Truthly[3674:184774] 0
2014-07-08 14:11:15.488 Truthly[3674:184774] results^
2014-07-08 14:11:15.489 Truthly[3674:184774] (
)
2014-07-08 14:11:15.490 Truthly[3674:184774] 0
2014-07-08 14:11:15.490 Truthly[3674:184774] search results^
2014-07-08 14:11:16.554 Truthly[3674:184774] Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2014-07-08 14:11:16.709 Truthly[3674:184774] (
)
2014-07-08 14:11:16.709 Truthly[3674:184774] 0
2014-07-08 14:11:16.710 Truthly[3674:184774] results^
2014-07-08 14:11:16.710 Truthly[3674:184774] (
)
2014-07-08 14:11:16.710 Truthly[3674:184774] 0
2014-07-08 14:11:16.711 Truthly[3674:184774] search results^
2014-07-08 14:11:17.798 Truthly[3674:184774] Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2014-07-08 14:11:17.964 Truthly[3674:184774] (
)
2014-07-08 14:11:17.965 Truthly[3674:184774] 0
2014-07-08 14:11:17.965 Truthly[3674:184774] results^
2014-07-08 14:11:17.965 Truthly[3674:184774] (
)
2014-07-08 14:11:17.966 Truthly[3674:184774] 0
2014-07-08 14:11:17.966 Truthly[3674:184774] search results^
```

And here is my m file.

```
#import "AllDataTableViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface AllDataTableViewController ()  <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {

}
@end

@implementation AllDataTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController


@synthesize searchBar;
@synthesize searchController;
@synthesize searchResults;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"popAgain"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        NSString *popAgain = @"false";
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:popAgain forKey:@"popAgain"];

    }
}




- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.className = @"TruthIsData";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"truthIsName";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;

}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {

        return self.objects.count;

    } else {
        //NSLog(@"how many in search results");
        //NSLog(@"%@", self.searchResults.count);
        return self.searchResults.count;

    }

}




-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"truthIsData"];
    //[query whereKey:@"truthIsName" containsString:searchTerm];

    NSArray *results  = [query findObjects];

    NSLog(@"%@", results);
    NSLog(@"%u", results.count);
    NSLog(@"results^");

   [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];

    NSPredicate *searchPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF == %@", searchTerm];
    searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate]];

    NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
    NSLog(@"%u", searchResults.count);
    NSLog(@"search results^");





}




- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];



    // Configure the cell
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"truthIsName"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User: %@", [object objectForKey:@"username"]];

    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        PFObject* object = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"truthIsName"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User: %@", [object objectForKey:@"username"]];
    }



    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    PFObject *obj = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *quickId = obj.objectId;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:quickId forKey:@"selectedTI"];
    //NSLog(quickId);


   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"selectedRequest" sender:self];


}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterResults:searchString];
    return YES;
}



@end
```

I feel like I have tried everything but I can't get this to work. Any suggestions would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: Are Parse class names case-sensitive? In one instance you have "TruthIsData" while in another you have "truthIsData". The fact that you're receiving back 0 results from Parse tells you that no objects match the query. You may as well test that querying code in isolation from your filtering code, because you're not even getting anything back to filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Parse class(table) is set as "TruthIsData" when you set the tables' self.parse.class
but in your filter method it is "truthIsData".

Querying Parse classes Are case-sensitive so whichever one is the correct name you have to change the wrong name and your objects will appear.